# Find and replace all crashes vs2015 and 2013

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2015

I am trying to do a find and replace all on the entire solution but everytime I try, it crashes visual studio with the message:

> Visual Studio 20** has stopped working

This only happens when I do a find and replace all on the entire solution or current project - it will work if I do it on all open files (but I don't want to go through and open all the files everytime I want to do this), and a find all in the entire solution works and it will always crash no matter how small the solution is - I tried it on a one file project

From looking around various reasons for VS crashing, I have tried the following with no success:

Clean and rebuild the solution

Deleting files in `%AppData%\..\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0\ComponentModelCache`

Starting in SafeMode

Running VS with logging, but it seems to crash before it logs the reason for the crash - see errors from log xml in code snippet below. I think these happen on load rather than when the crash happens as I have tried loading and then closing the vs and get the same errors.  For a full copy of the log, [check this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gg7pmqwu/)

```html
<entry>
    <record>235</record>
    <time>2016/06/03 09:12:57.703</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>PkgDef syntax or I/O error at line 1: Section header: missing closing bracket</description>
    <hr>80004005 - E_FAIL</hr>
    <path>The contents of this file have moved.</path>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>236</record>
    <time>2016/06/03 09:12:57.703</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Could not process PkgDef file</description>
    <hr>80004005 - E_FAIL</hr>
    <path>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\VsGraphics\RegisteredDefaultEngines.pkgdef</path>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>242</record>
    <time>2016/06/03 09:12:57.704</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>PkgDef syntax or I/O error at line 1: Section header: missing closing bracket</description>
    <hr>80004005 - E_FAIL</hr>
    <path>The contents of this file have moved.</path>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>243</record>
    <time>2016/06/03 09:12:57.704</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Could not process PkgDef file</description>
    <hr>80004005 - E_FAIL</hr>
    <path>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\VsGraphics\VsGraphicsLaunchHookPkg.pkgdef</path>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>1851</record>
    <time>2016/06/03 09:13:01.431</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Failed to read Version</description>
    <hr>80070002</hr>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>1852</record>
    <time>2016/06/03 09:13:01.431</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Binding Redirect / CodeBase entry from configuration hive is malformed, ignoring.</description>
    <hr>80070002</hr>
    <path>Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0_Config_16920\RuntimeConfiguration\dependentAssembly\bindingRedirection\{BB256134-B73E-47AA-93B4-C49FF433E5B1}</path>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>1885</record>
    <time>2016/06/03 09:13:01.817</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Loading UI library</description>
    <guid>{480D29DF-2B3D-445F-B055-FE2C74913A83}</guid>
    <hr>800a006f</hr>
    <errorinfo>Cannot find the requested resource: 'Menus.ctmenu'.</errorinfo>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>1886</record>
    <time>2016/06/03 09:13:01.971</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Loading UI library</description>
    <guid>{16CD70AB-0E04-4675-91FA-4910E09EAE56}</guid>
    <hr>800a006f</hr>
    <errorinfo>Cannot find the requested resource: 'Commands.ctmenu'.</errorinfo>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>1887</record>
    <time>2016/06/03 09:13:02.224</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Loading UI library</description>
    <guid>{2FFE45C4-5C73-493C-B187-F2E955FF875E}</guid>
    <hr>800a006f</hr>
    <errorinfo>Cannot find the requested resource: 'Menus.ctmenu'.</errorinfo>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>1889</record>
    <time>2016/06/03 09:13:02.255</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Loading UI library</description>
    <guid>{2EF1EC52-C8BF-4FE0-8ECE-BA9C0D5D1603}</guid>
    <hr>800a006f</hr>
    <errorinfo>Cannot find the requested resource: 'VSMenus.ctmenu'.</errorinfo>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>2291</record>
    <time>2016/06/03 09:13:04.454</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>Extension Manager</source>
    <description>Error loading extension: This VSIX does not apply to any product installed on this machine. The problem could be that the VSIX manifest&apos;s format is not recognized, or that the manifest has been corrupted. Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1. </description>
    <path>C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 14.0\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\VSGRAPHICS\</path>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>2292</record>
    <time>2016/06/03 09:13:04.493</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>Extension Manager</source>
    <description>Error loading extension: This VSIX does not apply to any product installed on this machine. The problem could be that the VSIX manifest&apos;s format is not recognized, or that the manifest has been corrupted. Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1. </description>
    <path>C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 14.0\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\VSGRAPHICS\</path>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>2293</record>
    <time>2016/06/03 09:13:04.500</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>Extension Manager</source>
    <description>Extension will not be loaded because an extension with the same ID &apos;Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.TeamExplorer.Extensions&apos; is already loaded at C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 14.0\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\P04KATKY.ORE\...</description>
    <path>C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 14.0\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\TEAMFOUNDATION\TEAM EXPLORER\</path>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>2294</record>
    <time>2016/06/03 09:13:04.501</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>Extension Manager</source>
    <description>Extension will not be loaded because an extension with the same ID &apos;148ffa77-d70a-407f-892b-9ee542346862&apos; is already loaded at C:\USERS\NGP\APPDATA\LOCAL\MICROSOFT\VISUALSTUDIO\14.0\EXTENSIONS\O3OMG1QP.PKM\...</description>
    <path>C:\USERS\NGP\APPDATA\LOCAL\MICROSOFT\VISUALSTUDIO\14.0\EXTENSIONS\JYRLXX0C.PDK\</path>
  </entry>
```

Has anyone had this problem, know how to solve it, or understand my log files enough to see what the problem is?

Comment: Have you tried using something else like SublimeText instead?

Comment: @phuzi, I don't really want to be loading a new program just to do a find and replace

Comment: Normally I'd agree but you've got to pick your battles... In this case it's probably going to be easier (and quicker) to do the search and replace in another tool than it is to try and figure out why VS 2013/15 keeps failing.

Comment: Also experiencing this bug. Tried several Find Replace cases. They all included RegEx, an input string, a pattern, a specific folder, and a specific file types. VS crashes only on certain regex patterns (for example ".*")

Comment: I had to do some large find and replaces, and also ran into this bug. I ended up using the Sublime with the Sublime_tfs plugin.  Didn't take too long to get going.